# ¿Como restarle un valor a un campo después de una inserción?

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día, busco la manera de que cuando haga una inscripción de un alumno se le reste un valor a un campo de otra tabla. Explico mejor tengo dos tablas, una llamada inscritos en donde guardo el id del estudiante y el id del curso de dicha inscripción.

Ahora necesito que cada vez que inscriba un estudiante se le reste un valor al campo cupos que esta en mi tabla cursos. Esta es la estructura de mis tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Allí esta, en resumen es que cuando haga una inscripción en el curso elegido por el estudiante se le reste uno al campo cupos, son 30 cupos por curso. Quien pueda aclararme esto, gracias. Hasta ahora no he intentado nada. Esto en PHP y MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que son 30 cupos por curso y se va restando 1 a medida que los usuarios van eligiendo esa asignatura, por lo que al final el total de cupos debería ser 0.

Para ello antes de hacer el `INSERT` deberías de comprobar que los cupos de ese curso son mayores que 0. Tan simple como almacenar el valor que te devuelva la siguiente consulta (modificando los valores a tu caso):

```
SELECT cupos FROM cursos_abiertos WHERE id = 1
```

Si la consulta te devuelve que los cupos son mayor que 0 entonces ya se puede hacer la consulta

```
if($cupos > 0){
    // primero haces el INSERT al curso
    // aquí haces el update. Como en la variable $cupos tienes almacenado el valor de cupos que le quedan al curso simplemente le restas 1 y haces el update, que seria algo así:

    $update = "UPDATE cursos_abiertos SET cupos = ($cupos - 1) WHERE id = 1;
}
```

Conclusión: 
**1.** Comprueba antes del `INSERT` que haya suficientes cupos
**2.** Si aún hay cupos, haces el `UPDATE` restando 1 al valor actual

Comment: Esa fue la fresa del postre gmarsi, esa comprobacion de la existencia de los cupos que acabas de decirme. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Ya que claramente haz dicho que no haz intentado nada tanto simplemente te dejo la simple lógica de lo que tendrías que hacer en [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql)

Ok, vamos por pasos, primero tendrías que insertar al estudiante (*el cual claramente ya debe existir en la tabla **X** que uses para los estudiantes*) en la tabla `inscritos`:

```
INSERT INTO inscritos (id_student, id_curso, activo) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
```

Claramente en este punto conoces el `id_curso` entonces ahora simplemente necesitarías realizar una actualización en la tabla `cursos_abiertos`

```
UPDATE cursos_abiertos SET cupos = cupos - 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

La sentencia anterior indica actualizar el campo `cupos` a  su mismo valor menos 1 donde el `id` del curso sea el ingresado anteriormente en la tabla `inscritos`

Comment: Saludos Jorius, entonces ha de quedarme asi:                               
$query = "INSERT INTO inscritos (id_student,id_curso,activo) VALUES ('$id_student'.'$id_curso',$activo)";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);

if($sql>0):
 $query2 = "UPDATE cursos_abiertos SET cupos = cupos - 1 WHERE id = '$id_curso'";
 $sql2 = $mysqli->query($query);
 header('Location:admin.php');
else:
 echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
endif;